# Using the session ID creation in PHP without actually sending the session ID

Tags: php, sessionid

I am creating a web service that (in an attempt to be RESTful) does not use cookies. My scheme for authentication is as follows.

- User `POST`s username and hashed password (over HTTPS) to `/sessions`.
- `/sessions` responds with the session ID as part of the response body.
- User authenticates all further requests by appending `?session_id=[session_id]` to the URL.

When implementing this, I would like to create a session ID, store it somewhere (file or database) and then manually insert the session ID as a part of the response body.

The existing session functions in PHP already do a lot of this (the ID generation and file storage), but I can't figure out how to only use those parts and not have the session ID sent to the user as a cookie.

Is this possible? Or do I need to implement my own session ID generation function (any tips?) and file/database storage?

Comment: session IDs in urls is generally a BAD idea. bookmarking such a url and then sharing it gives everyone access to that session. As well, sessions tend to expire, and bookmarking an explicit session will just confuse usrs when the link breaks through no fault of their own.

Comment: PHP uses cookies for session management by default. It is possible to set PHP to use a query string parameter. You might actually do better looking at a custom session handler. See the [PHP reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.customhandler.php)

Comment: @MarcB It's not intended to be seen by end users, it's a web service that provides an API, so there shouldn't be any bookmarking.

Comment: @MikeW It looks like using a custom session save handler allows me to overwrite the functionality I want to keep from PHP, and doesn't allow me to overwrite the functionality I want to change.

Comment: As a cookie or response body: It's not RESTful if you use sessions. However, it's no religion, so if you decide to break the "an URL always provide access to the same resource" part of REST anyway, I cannot see how using cookies would make it any worse.

Comment: It's not exactly sessions, it's more of an authentication token. The client `POST`s to `/sessions` and receives HTTP 201 Created with the location of the sessions/auth token. They then include this in every subsequent request, and upon logout can send `DELETE /sessions/abcdef123`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable the ini setting for session cookies.

```
ini_set('session.use_cookies', '0');
session_id($your_session_token);
session_start();
```

Example:

authentication api - .../sessions/

```
...
check username/password ... other things
...
ini_set('session.use_cookies', '0');
session_start();
$_SESSION['user_stuff'] = $stuff;
$_SESSION['other_things'] = $things;

...
print session_id() along with whatever else is needed in the response body
```

the actual service - .../some_other_service_url/?session_id=[session_id]

```
ini_set('session.use_cookies', '0');
session_id($_GET['session_id']);//I'm not sure where PHP will look for it by default and I'm too lazy to check, so I'm making sure its $_GET['session_id']
session_start();
if(!$_SESSION['user_stuff']) {
    session token is missing, invalid or expired. the client needs to reauthenticate
}

do some useful things
```

Comment: That sets the current session ID. I would like to still use PHP's session ID generation. And I believe setting it to not send cookies will still cause it to use a query string parameter.

Comment: It can only use the query string parameter to load the session (which as I understand is what you want). If you don't provide the ID it will either read it from the query string (if its there) or generate a new one. If you want to get the ID (newly generated or not) use `session_id()`. If you want to force it to create a new one use `session_regenerate_id`.